# How to distribute the results retrieved from database into individual pages?

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, distribute

I'm facing such a problem,
I have a database bank with lots of questions and their joined answers 'multiple choice system'!
 I wrote a PHP script to retrieve (15) questions each time a user enters the page, 'index.php' as a radio-buttons.

Now my bass asked me to change the method of showing the questions! so, instead of 15 questions at the same page! he asked to show one question per time, something like this:

```
================================================================================
1. Question TEXT:
a. 1st variant
b. 2nd variant
c. 3rd variant
d. 4th variant


<NEXT QUESTION> 
================================================================================
```

so by clicking on the button  which is a "submit" the script should redirect me to the second part of the file which must show the second question, and from the second as shown above to the third --> forth --> ... --> 15th question

```
================================================================================
1st question is: Correct //This part will check the correction/incorrection of the previous question -_-

2. Question2 TEXT:
a. 1st variant
b. 2nd variant
c. 3rd variant
d. 4th variant


<NEXT QUESTION> 
================================================================================
```

bottom line, I am able to bring a 15 question on the page and after checking the answers I give the results. but I could figure out how to distribute these questions into individual pages!! as

```
'index.php?question=1'
'index.php?question=2'
'index.php?question=3'
...
'index.php?question=15'
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: A simple solution could be to use jquery with an ajax call to a script  which returns one question each time you request it. But an interesting question is, do you use a special criteria in order to fetch these questions from the database?

Comment: Save each question, on each page, in a session variable -> `$_SESSION['questions'][$_GET['question']] = $question['id']`. Then on each page you can select a question not already in the `$_SESSION['question']` array.

Comment: @Cristian, Could you please gimme a hint, I am not that good in jQuery and Ajax, simply I retrieve the information from database and save "the checked answers" into an array then compare it to the database. That's all, I believe nothing is special here ))

Comment: @Sean thank you, I will try to realize that!! although the Ajax and jQuery seems to be more professional, but the results are what we care about!! ))

Comment: So, I immagined a solution like this: first of all you generate from your database a 10 questions set when the page first loads then, at every answer Is given by the user you just check if it's right or not with another small script, if the question is wrong you add an item in the $_SESSION ['wrong'] array whitch contains the id of the wrong answer. In the end you show these wrong answers with their relative right solution.

Comment: @Cristian: thank you for your point, I figured out something that worked for me "for the time being at least, I am not sure if it is considered as un-professional!! I'm gonna post in as an answer hoping for some advices!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so as I said, I wanted to distribute the results retrieved from one query into individual pages, and I came up with this idea,
1. Did the same query

```
SELECT * FROM database ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10
```

then I saved the IDz of the retrieved questions into an array just like that

```
$id = array();
$_SESSION[corr] = 0;
$_SESSION[incorr] = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) {
$id[] = $row[ID];
}
```

Then I saved the array into a SESSION to pass it in every required page as follows

```
$_SESSION[ID] = $id;
```

after that I set a link such as

```
echo "<a href=test.php?question=1>Click To Start</a>";
```

and last but not least did something like this

```
if ($_REQUEST['question'] == '1') {
$id = $_SESSION['id'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `id` = '$id[0]'") or die("Error" .mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

echo "<font color=green>Correct: " .$_SESSION[corr]. "</font></br>"; 
echo "<font color=red>Incorrect: " .$_SESSION[incorr]. "</font></br>";

echo "$row[v]<br>";
echo "<form action='test.php?question=2' method='POST'>";
echo "<input type=radio name=answer1 value=1>$row[o1]</input><br>";
echo "<input type=radio name=answer1 value=2>$row[o2]</input><br>";
echo "<input type=radio name=answer1 value=3>$row[o3]</input><br>";
echo "<input type=radio name=answer1 value=4>$row[o4]</input><br>";
echo "<input type=submit name=submit value=Check>";
echo "</form>";

$_SESSION['previous_id'] = $row['id'];
exit;
```

and in the next part "test.php?question=2"
I firstly checked if the previous question was answered correctly as the following

```
if ($_REQUEST['question'] == '2') {
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$answer = $_POST['answer1'];
$grade = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `id` = {$_SESSION['previous_id']}") or die();
$right = mysql_fetch_assoc($grade);

if ($answer == $right[g]) {
$_SESSION['corr']++;

echo "<font color=green>Correct</font></br>";

}
else {
$_SESSION['incorr']++;
echo "<font color=red>Incorrect, check lesson #".$right[lvl]."</font></br>"; 

}




$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `id` = '$id[1]'") or die("Error" .mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

echo "$row[v]<br>";
echo "<form action='test.php?question=3' method='POST'>";
echo "<input type=radio name=answer2 value=1>$row[o1]</input><br>";
echo "<input type=radio name=answer2 value=2>$row[o2]</input><br>";
echo "<input type=radio name=answer2 value=3>$row[o3]</input><br>";
echo "<input type=radio name=answer2 value=4>$row[o4]</input><br>";
echo "<input type=submit name=submit value=Check>";
echo "</form>";
$_SESSION['previous_id'] = $row['id'];
exit;

}
```

That worked just 100% as I wanted, but it is just not feeling professional, because I had to rewrite that code, or copy and edit the same above shown codes lots of times, considering I am trying to post 10 or 15 questions separately..

hopefully that helps some one else!